# Is a semaphore the best way to limit the number of pre-fetcher tasks in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

**Background:**

Im designing a service which stores files in a series of chunks (each file may be any number of bytes long, split up into roughly equally sized chunks). One of the requirements is that the API I'm building must be able to query for a file, re-assemble the chunks in the proper order and emit them in an output stream. In order to conserve resources but still provide some amount of buffering to increase performance, I have decided to implement this using a configurable number of pre-fetcher tasks that will run in a cached thread pool.

**Work I've done so far:**

In order to control the number of threads, I ended up using a semaphore initialized to the target concurrency level. That is, if I want to have 3 pre-fetcher tasks running, I initialize the semaphore to have an initial value of 3. There is an additional control mechanism to preserve the file chunk ordering as its written to the output stream, but that is outside of the scope of my question.

**My question:**

Is a semaphore the best way to manage the number of concurrent pre-fetchers? Typically Java has other control mechanisms to avoid the use of low-level concurrency controls, however, it really seems like it fits this particular implementation. I just want to see if there is a better option.

**Code:**

Note 1: the entityID + filename uniquely identify a file, and can be ignored

Note 2: part numbers (or file chunk ID) start at 0 and increase

```
/**
 * Assembles parts of a file into the provided output stream. This implementation
 * utilizes a fixed number of worker threads to pre-fetch data, and then re-assembles
 * the data chunks into the appropriate order when flushing the data to the stream.
 * For example, if a file has 10 chunks, and {@link #mFileFetchConcurrencyLevel} is
 * set to 3, then the first three parts are initially fetched. As parts are written
 * in increasing order, subsequent parts will be fetched. That is, once part 1 is
 * done being written (part 2 and 3 may have finished fetching before or after this,
 * it does not matter) then part 4 will start to be fetched.
 *
 * At the end of the fetch cycle, the output stream will be closed.
 *
 * @param entityID The owning entity
 * @param filename The file requested
 * @param os The stream to which the data will be written
 */
private void assembleFile(String entityID, String filename, OutputStream os) {
    final int nParts = getNumFileParts(entityID, filename);
    final AtomicInteger nextPartToFetch = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final AtomicInteger nextPartToWrite = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final Semaphore permission = new Semaphore(mFileFetchConcurrencyLevel);

    /* trivial case: nothing to do */
    if (nParts == 0) {
        try { os.close(); } catch (Exception e){}
        return;
    }


    while (nextPartToFetch.get() < nParts) {
        /* wait for other threads to finish writing file sections */
        try {
            permission.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // (omitting error handling)
            continue;
        }

        /* once permission is granted, start another data pre-fetcher. There are
         * a few steps in this process:
         *  1. Fetch the data
         *  2. Wait until the appropriate time to write the data, since data fetches
         *      may complete out-of-order. Otherwise, the output stream will have
         *      its data written out of order and the file will be corrupted
         *  3. Write the data
         *  4. Close output stream data after all parts are written
         */
        mThreadPool.submit(() -> {
            int responsiblePart = nextPartToFetch.getAndIncrement();
            /* 1. Fetch the data, this may take some time and will block */
            byte[] partData = getFilePart(entityID, filename, responsiblePart);

            synchronized (nextPartToWrite) {
                /* 2. Wait in line to write the data in the appropriate order */
                while (nextPartToWrite.get() != responsiblePart)
                    try { nextPartToWrite.wait(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                /* 3. Write the data */
                try {
                    os.write(partData);
                    os.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // (omitting error handling)
                }

                /* this lets other threads know its time to check if they should write data */
                nextPartToWrite.incrementAndGet();
                nextPartToWrite.notifyAll();

                /* we can now allow another prefetch thread to run */
                permission.release();
            }

            /* 4. Close the output stream. The thread with the last part is
             * responsible for closing the stream
             */
            if (responsiblePart == nParts - 1) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // (omitting error handling)
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's the common approach. You can generalize to reusable structures, e.g. a delay queue based on priority order, or decouple to make distributed version via message passing. There are only so many ways to implement a master-worker pattern, though, and simple enough to not need dedicated classes in j.u.c.

Comment: Bounding your thread pool size doesn't work for you in this case?

Comment: This thread pool is a shared resource for a number of background tasks across the API I'm building, and I want to benefit from other requests to create cached threads for each task rather than create a unique thread pool for each request that comes in.

Comment: You'll probably want to be careful to make sure the master completes when all of the workers have finished. I prefer not blocking threads in the pool waiting to maximize throughput by combining the results on the master's thread. In my [distributed variant](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BziJUj43dfDmMTE4RDlBNjdFQzgwRDRCODowLjE/view?usp=sharing) ('06) I used explicit tickets so that and master completed when all the work was published and it then consumed the in-flight tickets.